# Dialogflow Webhook V2 Account linking cannot get user profile info

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have managed to make Account Linking on Android using actions on google sdk and Dialogflow but can't make it work using the new Dialogflow V2 webhook.
It does ask permission to link account and the account linking does happen but I cannot access the user data like given_name, email, etc.
I have done everything required including creating the intent with actions_intent_SIGN_IN which gets called as expected except that I don't get the information that I should.

This is the code that is called to create sign in

```
function googleSignIn() {
    console.log('In googleSignIn')
    const conv = agent.conv()
    // conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'))
    // conv.ask('Hello')

    var payload = {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
        "data": {}
      }
    }

    // agent.add(payload)
    console.log('add googleSignIn payload')
    agent.add('Placeholder_google_payload')
    agent.add(new Payload(agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE, payload))
  }
```

This gets called when the intent is fired by Actions on Google

```
function getSignIn(agent) {
    console.log('In function getSignin: ')
    const conv = agent.conv()
    console.log('conv parts: ', JSON.stringify(conv.user))
    agent.add('User profile:', conv.user);
    // console.log('conv access token: ', JSON.stringify(conv.user.access.token))
  }
```

With help from Prisoner I managed to solve the problem. You basically just get the token which has to be decoded. This is the relevant code.

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // use npm i jsonwebtoken to get 
const profile = jwt.decode(conv.user.profile.token);
console.log('Profile: ', profile); 
// you can then get the elements from the profile (instead of payload)
// e.g.
console.log('Name: ', profile.name);
```

Comment: Aer you using Account Linking via OAuth or Google Sign In for Assistant?

Comment: Thanks Prisoner, I was actually checking your profile to see if you have answered any questions about this because your answers are good!

I am keeping it simple and using Google Sign in for Assistant.
Basically when I did this using Actions on google it was easy to define the app = dialogflow({client:....) and then the app object gave me all the information about sign in. 

I don't know how to do the same thing with Webhook. I tried using app the same way but it says undefined object. I am sure I am missing something very simple here to get to the Google sign in data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the user has signed in *once* using Google Sign In for Assistant, all further requests will contain an id token.

If you are using the actions-on-google library, the token will be in the `conv` object as `conv.user.profile.id` and the profile information itself (the "payload" of the id token) will be in `conv.user.profile.payload`.

If you're using the dialogflow-fulfillment library, you can get the `conv` object from `agent.getConv()`.

If you're using the multivocal library, the user profile is stored in the environment under `User/Profile` with the id token available under `User/IdentityToken` and `User/IsAuthenticated` will be set to true.

This will be sent to you for this session, and any future session as long as the user doesn't disconnect your Action from their account.

Comment: Actually I did try that but go this
info: Payload:   
 undefined   
End of payload:

This is the code that I am using in the welcome intent
function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`\n  \nWelcome to Mini Genie!`);
    const conv = agent.conv();

    const payload = JSON.stringify(conv.user.profile.payload);
    console.log('User:   \n', JSON.stringify(conv.user), '  \nEnd of User:');
    console.log('Payload:   \n', JSON.stringify(payload), '  \nEnd of payload:');
.....
}

Comment: Also, don't you need this somewhere somehow?
const app = dialogflow({
  debug: true,
  clientId: '991814768814-rfslo1iooq12apeqs4er2l62apcap.apps.googleusercontent.com'
});
I tried to use it in the main function but it doesn't work. I get app as undefined.

Comment: Ok I got it. I have to decode the id token though it was happening automatically when I was using the actions on google library.
Do you know an easy way to do this without using the JWT library?

Comment: Thanks, I used the jsonwebtoken to decode it and got the result. Now I hope it works on Iphone.
will mark as the correct answer once I see your comments on this :)

Comment: Sounds like you found the libraries. Tho I'm a little surprised that it isn't decoded when you called `conv()`. You should also make sure to do the validation of the identity token after you decode it. Please don't include code in comments - it is impossible to read - update the original question instead and mention you've done so in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Yes, I was trying to format the code in the comment but you can't do that. btw, it also does not have the payload field, just the token and according to google since it comes from the google function, you can assume its all validated so you don't have to validate it.

Comment: There is one more problem, a timing issue. When google sends it to the sign in intent, sometimes it doesn't have the profile info though after some time it does have it. There is no place to put a promise so I have to figure out what to do. Also, what about the extra parameters that are sent whereas this has only agent.

Comment: Not sure I'm following what you mean by "what about the extra parameters". You can update your original question to elaborate on the current question, or post a new question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am also facing this timing issue. Sometimes profile is available in the conv while other time it is not available. Is a bug in dialog flow ??

Comment: @Ajit - Do you have some examples of the timing issue? Can you post it as a new StackOverflow question?

Comment: @Prisoner I posted it as a new question. Here is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696012/actions-intent-sign-in-doesnt-have-profile-data-under-conv-user-profile